# GMSAutocompleteFetcher country restriction

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

I'm telling GMSAutocompleteFetcher to restrict the autocompletion to be within 'US', but it's not listening to me and returning results from other countries too.

Below is how I'm telling it.

```
self.autocompleteFetcher = GMSAutocompleteFetcher()
self.autocompleteFetcher.autocompleteFilter?.type = .Address
self.autocompleteFetcher.autocompleteFilter?.country = "US"
```

Can you guys please help with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: in this place try with once in some another country

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I tried but still no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know it's old question but I will try to answer it.
You have to initialize the filter first and then pass it to the fetcher's init as a parameter.

```
let fetcherFilter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
fetcherFilter.country = "BG"
fetcher = GMSAutocompleteFetcher(bounds: nil, filter: fetcherFilter)
```

Comment: Yep! I thought of answering it here but forgot. Thanks for posting.